# Angular Property 'content' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

So the code is simple, I have a component where I want to render information (if exists) and I get the error when the component does not exist.

So the post-list.component.html looks like this:

```
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{ post.title }}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <!-- <mat-panel-description>
        {{post.description}}
      </mat-panel-description> -->
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p *ngIf="posts.length >= 0">No posts added yet</p>
```

And the post-list.components.ts looks like this>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  posts = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I get this error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvwu7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have defined a type for your `posts` property. When you just do

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  posts = [];
  ...
}
```

typescript deduces the type for the `posts` property from its value `[]`. And from an empty array without any typing information it decuces `never[]`, thus it assumes the following

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  posts: never[] = [];
  ...
}
```

To fix this, define a type for your `posts` property like

```
export interface IPost {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  ...
}

export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  posts: IPost[] = [];
  ...
}
```

Thus, typescript will deduce the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to properly type your `posts` property:

```
interface Post {
  title:string;
  content: string;
}


export class PostListComponent {
  posts: Post[] = []; // <-- proper typings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In VS code just giving the error, because typescript is validating the types, there is no type is defined in the angular code itself.

ideally, you can define the post type somewhere out of the PostListComponent class

```
export interface Post {
 title: string;
 content: string;
}
```

In your PostListComponent define the type like this

```
posts: Post[] = [];
```