# Angular: Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a member. Unusual problem

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Im following a tutorial but I got stuck. not sure why I'm getting an error.
error on visual studio code is "Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'never' does not contain such a member" for both post.title and post.content

```
<mat-accordion multi=True *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>
      {{ post.content }}
    </p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf=" posts.length <= 0" > no posts added yet</p>
```

and in app.component.ts
I am getting an error: "Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type" and "Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' "

this specific error is at the onPostadded

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ang-project';

  storedPost = [] ;

  onPostAdded(post) {
    this.storedPost.push(post);
  }
}
```

let me know if I need to show more code of different files.
I would appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT:
the for the function "*ngFor="let post of posts", Posts for some reason is type never : (property) PostListComponent.posts: never[]

I am not sure why it is like that.

I should add that posts variable is a const array.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
  enteredContent = '';
  enteredTitle = '';
  postCreated = new EventEmitter();

  onAddPost() {
    const posts = {
      title: this.enteredTitle,
      content: this.enteredContent
    };
    this.postCreated.emit(posts);
  }
}
```

this is post-list-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})


export class PostListComponent {
  // posts = [
  //   {title:'first post', content:'this is the first post'},
  //   {title:'second post', content:'this is the second post'},
  //   {title:'third post', content:'this is the third post'}
  // ];

  @Input() posts: IPost[] = [];
```

I'm getting an error: " Cannot find name 'IPost' "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Property 'content' does not exist on type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752072/angular-property-content-does-not-exist-on-type-never)

Comment: I am sorry, I still need help. The link shows a similar question , nearly identical but I'm still stuck.

Comment: The problem is, that `storedPost = [] ;` does not allow typescript to deduce a type for your `posts` array (like written in the answer in the other question) so you have to define a type for it (like written in the answer to the other post) The solution is exactyl the same as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752129/3776927  `storedPosts : IPost[] = []`

Comment: Can you show `PostListComponent` typescript file?, I think you need to add an interface for `posts` something like this `posts: { title: string; content: string; }`

Comment: I have edited the piece of code to the question. How will the interface be added? keep in mind the tutorial I am following did not need to do any of what you suggested and I am not sure why.

Comment: Well you need to define your IPost interface somewhere. Just look at the linked answer. It's exactly your problem ...

Comment: okay, I did that but it caused another problem. " app-post-list' is not a known element:"   the component is no longer recognizable. that in app-component.html

Answer (score 0):

I d'ont know if this :

```html
<mat-accordion multi=True *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>
      {{ post.content }}
    </p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf=" posts.length <= 0" > no posts added yet</p>
```

is the template of `AppComponent`. But if it is, so don't check `*ngIf="posts.length > 0"` should be `*ngIf="storedPost.length > 0"`, `*ngIf="posts.length <= 0"` should be `*ngIf="storedPost.length <= 0"` and `*ngFor="let post of posts"` should be `*ngFor="let post of storedPost"`. Because you add your post on submission in storedPost

Comment: I dont think that will work because storedPost is in app.component while the piece of code you are referring to is in a subfolder Post-list for all the post-list-component stuff

Comment: ho ok, there is no reference of title of page for the templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is how you add interface
interface IPost {
 title: string;
 content: string;
}

export class PostListComponent {
  @Input() posts: IPost[] = [];
}
```

Angular now generates a project with strict mode by default and you have to specify types for variables, Maybe the tutorial is old or they have disabled strict mode.

Read [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#checking-of-ngfor) you will get idea

Comment: that did fix one of the problems but the other one in app-component is still there and cause another problem where the entire post-list-component was not recognized. "'app-post-list' is not a known element:"

Comment: @ShadDimitri Can you create a reproducible stackblitz, so that it will be easier to find the issue

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykf1jp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fposts%2Fpost-list%2Fpost-list.component.ts
this link should be the stackblitz for the current position im on the tutorial.
stackblitz is not showing where exactly are the errors

Comment: I think your stackblitz is incomplete and broken.

Comment: I really don't know what is causing it. I am not getting that specific error when I run it on my computer. It seems that I am importing everything correctly